# Check if value exists in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I will preface this by saying I've been stuck on this for a couple days, I am obviously new and know I'm missing something simple. I've tried so many ways. Security is not an issue yet and I am just trying to learn on my own server.

I always get 'something found' even when I know the value does not exists. I am trying to enter a phrase into an input field, press submit and see if the value already exists in the table

Sorry for the dumb question.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
// error_reporting(0);
// ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
// exit();
//echo '<pre>';  print_r($user_info);  echo '</pre>';

if ( (isset($_POST['lookup'])) && ($_REQUEST['lookup'] =='1')) {
    echo 'you\'ve entered a keyword, lets see if it exsists!';
    $looksql = "SELECT * FROM `crm3`.`keywords` WHERE `KW0` LIKE '".$_POST['lookup']."' ORDER BY `ID` ASC ";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql)) {
        echo '<br>someting found';
    } else { echo '<br>nothing found'; }
} else {
    echo '<br>please enter a keyword to start the search';
}
?>

<br><br><br>
<form method="POST" action="./?action=kwcheck">
    <input type="hidden" name="lookup" value="1" />
    keyword lookup: <input type="text" name="keyword" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done almost everything right, except the condition. Your condition always gives a **truthy value**. It should be:

```
// Query the MySQL server.
$result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
  // Rows are there.
  echo '<br>someting found';
} else {
  // No rows are there.
  echo '<br>nothing found';
}
```

If you want it functional, you can create a function that return a boolean value: `true`, if items found, `false`, if not.

```
function recordsCount($looksql) {
  // Get the connection from global scope.
  global $db;
  // Query the MySQL server.
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql);
  // Return if the count is greater than 0 or not.
  return (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0);
}
```

**Security concern:** Use parameterised queries. Putting `$_POST` (or any user input `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE`, etc.) in a query opens you to SQL injections. Also if you want an exact match use `=`, not `LIKE`. The `LIKE` should be for partial matching and use wildcards (`%`). Thanks to [chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85).

Comment: I was still getting an error because my query was wrong, it should have been:
`code`$_POST['keyword'] instead of $_POST['lookup']`code`

Maybe I can take this one step further and have it show me the row ID of result?

Answer (score 0):

You have done wrong

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql)){// this is always true as query will be executed always    
     echo '<br>someting found';    
}
```

above code always executed because it is like if query executed then so echo message  and so if condition always be true try below code

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql);    
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
     echo '<br>someting found';
}
```

Comment: How is this different or better than my answer? Just curious.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i have not said anything that your answer is wrong or anything else

Comment: You could have at least formatted or indented the code.

Comment: I didn't mean any offence dude. Just curious. `:)`

Comment: I am gonna vote it up once you indent it nicely. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$looksql = "SELECT * FROM `crm3`.`keywords` WHERE `KW0` LIKE '%".$_POST['lookup']."%' ORDER BY `ID` ASC ";
```

use `%` after `like`

Comment: This wouldn't explain why the OP is getting results. It could be the answer if the OP weren't getting results.

Comment: Yes! and thank you i miss $result = mysqli_query($db, $looksql) is just return a object of result